# BlockCypher Send Transaction

Tags: transactions

I am trying to implement the BlockCypher Ethereum API following the docs here: 
https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#transaction-api

I am using the Test Network **/beth/test**, rather than **/eth/main**.

I successfully created 2 addresses and called the faucet to fill one address with some 1000000000000000000 wei.

But then I can’t seem to be able to send a valid transaction…
Here are all (test) info:

**ADDRESS 1**

```
{
"private": "42eb005cbebd33f55b821864fcdc0755876317345ac9d8ad2bf94d734f78395f",
"public": "04c7238abb2e99c50ef3e4fabe21dbf2701f9dc60de24b40e743e84745984957ba7059a3e0b38c226b3580a95ed0e154fba407d089f5c02f90aa5797ead7fc190e",
"address": "7a9373010ce86d8fcd7dd46588d351cddabe7ce8"
```

}

**ADDRESS 2**

```
{
"private": "4a62456df43b89244d349948008064cfe1279ef3a632823f30b371ac54f879a1",
"public": "046c01b338e3c5224aa70fa302fefa5c9767d0f79aa16327e703d01924e894809460b22ab52974706543682d8e16063fd6cbd302b052762a3be5d7720efc4d2fa9",
"address": "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"
```

}

Address 2 contains 1000000000000000000 wei, and I am trying to send 1200000000000000 wei to Address 1.

I use the New Transaction method, I send this:

```
{"inputs":[{"addresses": ["73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"]}],"outputs":[{"addresses": ["7a9373010ce86d8fcd7dd46588d351cddabe7ce8"], "value": 1200000000000000}]}
```

And I get this response:

```
{
"tx": {
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": 0,
    "hash": "4e875a673e59f0b2d16123659b3a72a8d818a7cb832c5ed1a4bbf8f5b0a4ee87",
    "addresses": [
        "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"
    ],
    "total": 1200000000000000,
    "fees": 21000000000000,
    "size": 43,
    "gas_limit": 21000,
    "gas_price": 1000000000,
    "received": "2018-05-27T13:51:23.247159854Z",
    "ver": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 1,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "sequence": 0,
            "addresses": [
                "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "value": 1200000000000000,
            "addresses": [
                "7a9373010ce86d8fcd7dd46588d351cddabe7ce8"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"tosign": [
    "8b765bd6c2065f612eb00aa55c50759049779cff50151395aefc5a3dafa5cc10"
]
```

}

Then I use Signer with the ToSign from the New Transaction response, and a Hex-Encoded Private Key of Address 2:

```
signer 8b765bd6c2065f612eb00aa55c50759049779cff50151395aefc5a3dafa5cc10 34613632343536646634336238393234346433343939343830303830363463666531323739656633613633323832336633306233373161633534663837396131
```

I get this signature:

```
30440220644db87755b0a8620e7e52bd64977c79350c0989afd587090be13a8f76efbf3a0220463eb6351c839b086f5874f6a125ec4723fb30eb26a6a831600cb4d3034cd9d3
```

So then I try the Send Transaction method of BlockCypher, here’s my request:

```
{
"tx": {
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": 0,
    "hash": "4e875a673e59f0b2d16123659b3a72a8d818a7cb832c5ed1a4bbf8f5b0a4ee87",
    "addresses": [
        "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"
    ],
    "total": 1200000000000000,
    "fees": 21000000000000,
    "size": 43,
    "gas_limit": 21000,
    "gas_price": 1000000000,
    "received": "2018-05-27T13:51:23.247159854Z",
    "ver": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 1,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "sequence": 0,
            "addresses": [
                "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "value": 1200000000000000,
            "addresses": [
                "7a9373010ce86d8fcd7dd46588d351cddabe7ce8"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"tosign": [
    "8b765bd6c2065f612eb00aa55c50759049779cff50151395aefc5a3dafa5cc10"
],
"pubkeys": ["046c01b338e3c5224aa70fa302fefa5c9767d0f79aa16327e703d01924e894809460b22ab52974706543682d8e16063fd6cbd302b052762a3be5d7720efc4d2fa9"],
"signatures": ["30440220644db87755b0a8620e7e52bd64977c79350c0989afd587090be13a8f76efbf3a0220463eb6351c839b086f5874f6a125ec4723fb30eb26a6a831600cb4d3034cd9d3"]
```

}

And I get back this error:

```
"Address 0xF6A14d976c86bDbe050cA9426aD491d750be33B1 computed from signature differs from provided one 73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090."
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

I tried several things already, read a few similar issues online, but still no luck.

I also tried the Raw Transaction method of BlockCypher, and also no luck there..

I am not clear what it means as “raw hex-encoded transaction”, I tried to send the Hex-Encoded input I sent to New Transaction:

```
{"inputs":[{"addresses": ["73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090"]}],"outputs":[{"addresses": ["7a9373010ce86d8fcd7dd46588d351cddabe7ce8"], "value": 1200000000000000}]}
```

So I sent to https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/beth/test/txs/push?token=[mytoken] this:

```
{"tx":"22696E70757473223A5B7B22616464726573736573223A205B2237336265666563323735313063363463333033643832313931656166323736613934363033303930225D7D5D2C226F757470757473223A5B7B22616464726573736573223A205B2237613933373330313063653836643866636437646434363538386433353163646461626537636538225D2C202276616C7565223A20313230303030303030303030303030307D5D"}
```

But I get the error:

```
“rlp: expected input list for types.TxData”.
```

Please, any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key you're passing to the signer tool (`3461...`) does not match either addresses you're using for the transaction. As Address 2 is the sender in your example, you should be using its private key instead (`4a62...`).

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, I appreciate it! the Sender private key is 4a62456df43b89244d349948008064cfe1279ef3a632823f30b371ac54f879a1, I hex encode this and get 34613632343536646634336238393234346433343939343830303830363463666531323739656633613633323832336633306233373161633534663837396131. Then I send this to signer along with the hex encoded "tosign" that from 8b765bd6c2065f612eb00aa55c50759049779cff50151395aefc5a3dafa5cc10 becomes 8b765bd6c2065f612eb00aa55c50759049779cff50151395aefc5a3dafa5cc10. They should be both hex encoded, right?

Comment: Yes, but the private key we return is *already* hex encoded. So you can provided it as-is to the signer. You only need to hex-encode if you start with binary data (or convert if if you have formats, like WIF).

Comment: That's it! darn.. thanks so much, I did not realize that.

Comment: Both tosign and private key seems already hex encoded... i simply passed both to signer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put in the

```
"pubkeys": ["046c01b338e3c5224aa70fa302fefa5c9767d0f79aa16327e703d01924e894809460b22ab52974706543682d8e16063fd6cbd302b052762a3be5d7720efc4d2fa9"],
```

at the end.

I haven't used the test net for eth... but since they say its the same thing...

try this instead.

> curl -sd '{ "tx": { "block_height": -1, "block_index": 0, "hash":
>   "4e875a673e59f0b2d16123659b3a72a8d818a7cb832c5ed1a4bbf8f5b0a4ee87",
>   "addresses": [ "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090" ], "total":
>   1200000000000000, "fees": 21000000000000, "size": 43, "gas_limit":
>   21000, "gas_price": 1000000000, "received":
>   "2018-05-27T13:51:23.247159854Z", "ver": 0, "double_spend": false,
>   "vin_sz": 1, "vout_sz": 1, "inputs": [ { "sequence": 0, "addresses": [
>   "73befec27510c64c303d82191eaf276a94603090" ] } ], "outputs": [ {
>   "value": 1200000000000000, "addresses": [
>   "7a9373010ce86d8fcd7dd46588d351cddabe7ce8" ] } ] }, "tosign": [
>   "8b765bd6c2065f612eb00aa55c50759049779cff50151395aefc5a3dafa5cc10" ],
>   "signatures":
>   ["30440220644db87755b0a8620e7e52bd64977c79350c0989afd587090be13a8f76efbf3a0220463eb6351c839b086f5874f6a125ec4723fb30eb26a6a831600cb4d3034cd9d3"]}'
>   https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/beth/test/txs/send?token=yourblockcyphertoken

you might need to create a new txskeleton... I don't know how long they are valid for... but since you got that part down, shouldn't be a problem. just sign the new tosign string with the signer and should be good.

Comment: Unfortunately even without the pubkeys I get the same error.. I really can't figure out what is wrong. thinking of using another API and way to do eth transactions at this point.. but thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

"input" is the receiver & "output" is the sender. In your example you have that backwards. The signer PK must match the "output" address.